# Why does my stand-alone WordPress script terminate with zero output?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a script that works for the most part. It fetches some data from a 3rd party API, and then it should create WordPress posts from the data.

Everything runs fine up until I need to use WP classes, at that point, I add the line `require_once('/var/www/html/wp-load.php');` to my script.

When I do this, my script will terminate instantly when I run it, with zero output. The result of `$?` is `0`

If I add an `echo "hello\n";` statement before the require line, I see:

> hello
>   PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at [redacted]) in [redacted]

If I add an `echo "hello\n";` statement after the require line, it doesn't appear in the output, just the warnings.

I've also tried adding the following before the `require` statement:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', '1');                                                                                                                                            ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
ini_set('log_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_log', '/tmp/php-errors.log');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('/var/www/html/wp-load.php');
```

To invoke the script, I simply enter `php run_script.php` on my shell.

Update:

The code I currently have, with troubleshooting steps included:

```
session_start();

ini_set('error_reporting', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
ini_set('log_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_log', '/tmp/php-errors.log');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

error_log('first error');

require_once('/var/www/html/wp-load.php');

error_log('second error');
```

Comment: So what do the warnings say? Do you just get the `Cannot send session cookie` warning if you have the `echo` after the `require_once`? You're not allowed any DOM output before the headers are sent.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any output at all before you include the script.

Comment: There is no output before the require statement, I simply added it for debugging purposes, just to see if I could get some kind of output.

Comment: If I add the statement `define('SHORTINIT', true);` I can get output after requiring `load.php`, but then I get errors about classes not found such as `WP_Query`.

Comment: Just in case, try adding `session_start` before the `require_once` and see if the error still persists.

Comment: I added that to the beginning, but I get the same behavior. No output after the `require` statement. I also tried `error_log('first error');` and `error_log('second error');` before and after the `require` statement. The first error appears in the `/tmp/php-errors.log`, the 'second error' does not.

Comment: At a guess, the Wordpress script (`wp-load.php`) is disabling error reporting. You can set it to debug mode with `define('WP_DEBUG', true)` **before** you include their scripts. See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: I finally found the problem... it was a plugin issue. It was Force SSL to be precise. I discovered this by adding: `echo "hello\n";` lines in the core code starting at `wp-load.php` and then continuing until I got no output, and that helped narrow it down.